# Search for file content with swiper-all or similar interface

Tags: search, files

I've been using swiper-all to search for content in buffers. This works really great as I easily can navigate between the files and select the ones I want to work with. Is there some way I can use a similar interface to search in files on disk. E.g. recursively in current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to install [RipGrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep), `counsel-rg` (included in [counsel](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper)) could offer the interface you are looking for.

From its docstring:

> Grep for a string in the current directory using rg.

Comment: This is perfect! :) I can search in the minibuffer, navigate matched files and press enter to open as a buffer. Thanks!